# Gatsby fails after using Sass files with '@use 'sass:color'

Tags: sass, gatsby

I'm setting up a Gatsby Project with `gatsby-plugin-sass`.

my `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-resolve-src',
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

I have the following styles **file structure**:

```
|
|src
|-styles
|--base
|--- _variables.scss
|--components
|--- _Buttons.scss
|--- ...
|--main.scss
```

Im my `_Buttons.scss` file I'm **importing** like this:

```
@import '../base/variables';
@use 'sass:color as *;
```

When I'm trying to use the **sass color functions** like this (as specified on https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules)

```
%buttons-focus {
  background-color: color.adjust($primary-color, $alpha: -0.5);
}
```

I get the following Error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...nd-color: color": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".adjust($primary-co"
```

In my main.scss I'm importing styles like this:

```
@import './components/Buttons';
```

---

Am I overseeing something?
I've tried changing up `@use` with `@import`, with no luck. For me it seems like the gatsby-sass-plugin is not aware of sass modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gatsby-plugin-sass` uses `node-sass` under the hood.  But in order to support built-in modules with @use, you need to configure `gatsby-plugin-sass` to use `dart-sass` instead. See below.

#### [Built-In Modules - sass-lang](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules)

> Only Dart Sass currently supports loading built-in modules with @use. Users of other implementations must call functions using their global names instead.

#### [Alternative Sass Implementations - gatsby-plugin-sass](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sass/#alternative-sass-implementations)

> By default the node implementation of Sass (node-sass) is used. To use the implementation written in Dart (dart-sass), you can install sass instead of node-sass and pass it into the options as the implementation:

```
npm install --save-dev sass
```

---

```
gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    options: {
      implementation: require("sass"),
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Likewise - I spent some time before I found this, so I've filled a request to add some docs/errors which help identify the problem: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2991